# present specific view controller when tap on push notification

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am new to **push notification** concepts and understood the basics of push notifications. But, I am not getting to present or push a specific view controller when tapping on push notification. And the same time how to handle dependency presenting view controller(example: if required same data from the server along with notification data to present view controller, how to handle it)

And how to handle notification if the app is in the foreground, background, or closed scenarios.

Please help me, Thank you.